# Lubuntu Not Shutting Down, But Restarting

Tags: 12.10, shutdown, ibm

I have Lubuntu 12.10 on an IBM Netvista. For some odd reason, whenever I click "Shut Down" from the logout menu in the taskbar, it goes to the "BOOT: IBM: PRESS F12 TO CHANGE BOOT SETTINGS" screen with the IBM logo, then it goes to Lubuntu again and it logs me back in. Any way to get it to shut down right?'

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo poweroff`?  If that doesn't work try `sudo shutdown` which will shut the OS down to a point where you can safely power it off with the power button (like Windows 95).

Comment: @Seth I think that the "Shut Down" is sudo shutdown. Any way to get it to act like sudo poweroff?

Comment: Have you tried either of them?  That's what I wanted to know...

Comment: @Seth Sorry, other way around. "Shut Down" acts just like sudo poweroff. Sudo shutdown is the Windows 95-like action that waits in SUM. But I am looking for it to actually power off. Thanks.

Comment: Does `shutdown -P now` work for you? See here for more information: http://serverfault.com/questions/191537/shutdown-what-is-difference-between-power-off-and-halt

Comment: `Shutdown -P now` does not work. It restarts the computer. So what should I do?